# Recursive parsing strings

Tags: python, parsing, recursion, dictionary

Is there a way to recursively parse the string to get the `dict`?

**string:**

```
string = 'a {\
    b: text;\
    c {\
        d: text;\
    }\
}';
```

**out:**

```
{
    'a' : {
        'b': 'text',
        'c': {
            'd' : 'text';
        }
    }
}
```

**upd:**
I'm new in Python, and I don't have a ready solution in the form of a library and etc, I want to understand the logic (any code if it possible or theory) of the algorithm for this problem

Comment: Can you show us the code you have problems so this turns into a specific programming-related question?

Comment: @Niklas B., I'm new in Python, but i want to write a small parser which transforms a string into `dict`. And I want to understand the algorithm

Comment: So you haven't tried anything yourself? That's not a good starting point for asking a question on this site.

Comment: @Yeah, I tried to solve this problem myself, but I don't have the skills to understand the logic of the algorithm

Comment: It's no problem to add non-functional code to the question. We will help you fix and adjust it, if that's at all possible.

Comment: @Niklas B., I don't understand how to approach this question, I don't have enough theoretical base!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) module.

> The pyparsing module is an alternative approach to creating and executing simple grammars, vs. the traditional lex/yacc approach, or the use of regular expressions. The pyparsing module provides a library of classes that client code uses to construct the grammar directly in Python code.

For a case like this, you would write the grammar that describes the string you are trying to parse, and avoid writing the parser.

**Update** (per comment): If one was interested in learning about the *theoretical basis* behind parsing strings such as these, then you need to understand what your goal is. This problem, in a more general form, is parsing a **context-free language**. You have a set of rules, known as a **grammar** that dictates the hierarchy of the data structure from the input. A good place to start reading (from an educational perspective) is the [Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

Comment: If it's really practical problem, I'd use JSON or YAML.

Comment: @Hooked, Thanks, but I don't have a ready solution in the form of a library, I want to understand the logic of the algorithm for this problem

Comment: @tomas I've found that _almost always_, writing your own parser is difficult, buggy and often not-maintainable. What you want to write is a _grammar_, a set of rules for parsing your data and let a parsing library take care of it. You'll end up learning more if you can make the distinction between the two!

Comment: @Hooked, My main goal - a `theoretical basis` for how to do it myself. I need more practice :)

Answer (score 2):

Writing a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) for this shouldn't be too difficult. There are [tutorials](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm) out there that describe how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`lepl`](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/) parser library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lepl import AnyBut, Delayed, Drop, DroppedSpace

def Parser():
    dict_ = Delayed()
    str_ = AnyBut('{}:;')[1::'n',...]

    with DroppedSpace():
        pair = str_ & Drop(':') & str_ & Drop(';') > tuple
        value = str_ & dict_ > tuple
        dict_ += Drop('{') & (pair | value)[:] & Drop('}') > dict
        return value > dict

print(Parser().parse("a {  b: text;  c { d: text; }}")[0])
```

#### Output

```
{'a': {'c': {'d': 'text'}, 'b': 'text'}}
```

See also [Python parsing tools](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html).

To understand the theory behind the code you could read *a book* that talks about lexical analysis (regular expressions and finite automata), syntax analysis (EBNF, context-free grammars, LL parsers).